# rebooting from dvd but keeps starting windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have created the ubuntu dvd but when i choose to boot from dvd drive on start up it automaticallt loads windows 7. Please can you help??

Comment: What program did you use to burn the dvd? Some require you to select an option to make it bootable.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you burned the DVD correctly?  What's happened to me before is the burning software burned the *.iso directly to the disc, instead of copying the contents of the image to the disc.  It's a frustratingly simple solution if you've already checked the BIOS boot properties.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change your BIOS settings to 'Boot' from the CD/DVD first.

Jago G.

Answer (score 0):

CD wasnt burned right.

Do you have one of the following ---

1. USB flash drive?
2. Smartphone with an “extra” Sd card?
3. A backup Xbox harddrive? (My brother had one that he used once to tranfer stuff to a new Xbox.

If you have no USB flash drive, but you do have a smart phone, You could do the following without losing any data on your smart phone. Depending on the model, and if you have anything installed on the external card, youd have to move it back.

1. plug in phone, turn on USB storage
2. Use Universal USB installer → its on the Ubuntu “install from USB” instructions. DO NOT use the “Format” box. I repeat, Do not format.

There is no need to format, chances are you have more than 700 Mbs free on Your SD card, all it will do is copy the data to it.
You can use your phone as a usb drive.

Final step: Reboot your computer, and enter the “boot menu” 
It might be F1, or F8 or even ESC. It should be listed in the bottom of the screen at boot.

If its not listed, go into the bios (There should be a key marked) → Find your boot settings and set the FIRST as Boot from USB (Your phone will be listed, probly as “Android phone” or “Motorola” or something like that.

Make sure “USB storage is toggled.

Of course, if you dont have a smart phone, this entire thing is useless. 
If you have a USB drive, then just use the USB Installer, and select that.